# Ubuntu 16.04 Cannot install MySQL

Tags: mysql, 16.04

After installing Ubuntu 16.04 and in the process of setting up a lampp stack. I tried to install MySQL as usual using the code below:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

However I get the below return from the terminal:

```
niall@niall:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate
```

Never came across this with an LTS before.

Comment: `sudo apt install mysql-server-core-5.7`